# How to handle invalid keys in NewCBCDecrypter example?

Tags: go, encryption

I found an example for the usage of CBC decrypter:
https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewCBCDecrypter

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString("6368616e676520746869732070617373")
    ciphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString("73c86d43a9d700a253a96c85b0f6b03ac9792e0e757f869cca306bd3cba1c62b")
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]

    if len(ciphertext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, ciphertext)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", ciphertext)
}
```

It works fine. But if I modify the key to make it invalid then it returns some strange characters instead of throwing an error.
How could I make it more programmer friendly by throwing an error if the key is invalid?

Comment: This is the difference between encryption and authentication. Without the latter, you cannot determine if the key or cipher text is valid.

Comment: In CBC mode the input is almost always [padded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7). It must be unless the input length is a multiple of the block size, and even then padding is applied because the padding will be invalid after decrypting with an incorrect key, and that can be easily detected.

Comment: Peter's answer could solve the issue if the original text was not equal to the block size (16). Then the decrypted text would be right padded with \b characters, which could be detected: strings.HasSuffix(string(ciphertext), "\b") Unfortunately the decrypted text is the following: exampleplaintext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I make it more programmer friendly by throwing an error if the key is invalid?

You cannot. That simply isn't how this stuff works. You supply a key and this key is used to decipher the input. There is no "correct" or "wrong" key here, there is just a key here.

You might be able to inspect the deciphered output: If you know the output always starts with some magic prefix or is a well-formed XML or anything you can check reliably after deciphering you can fail. But there is really nothing intrinsic to a key being wrong or right.